# Como separar uma string por vírgulas, exceto quando tiver um espaço depois

Tags: javascript, array, string, split

Tenho uma string e preciso separá-la em um *array*. Porém, o caractere separador precisa ser a vírgula (`,`), mas se tiver um espaço logo depois ("`,` ") ela seja preservada na separação.

Estou tentando fazer isso com `split`, mas não estou conseguindo. Exemplo do que quero:

```
string = "1,0,true,Yes, please";
```

Eu preciso de:

```
array = ["1","0","true","Yes, please"]
```

Comment: Não entendi o que vc quis dizer com "a ',' precisa ser preservada"

Comment: @JrD acredito que seja a virgula precisa ser preservada

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar a seguinte [expressão regular](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) para fazer a divisão:

```
/,(?! )/
```

Sendo:

- `,` ⇒ seleciona todas as vírgulas;
- `(?! )` ⇒ um [lookahead negativo](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) que garante que não possa haver espaços **após** a vírgula.

Desse modo, você pode fazer assim:

```js
const string = '1,0,true,Yes, please'
const splittedString = string.split(/,(?! )/)

console.log(splittedString)
```

Comment: Se não me engano, no `split` não precisa colocar a flag `g`, por padrão ele separa a string inteira...

Comment: É verdade! Obrigado pela observação... Acabei de testar aqui no console e realmente não faz diferença. Editei a resposta. ;)

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Sugestão, troque espaço por `\s`, esse meta-caractere é usado para diferentes tipos de espaçamentos, como espaço, tab, quebras, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Vai ser sempre nesse formato? Se sim você pode usar esse código:

```js
var string = "1,0,true,yes, please";
var array = [];
var preservado = string.substr(string.indexOf(", ") - 3);
array = string.substr(0, string.indexOf(', ') -4).split(',');
array.push(preservado);
console.log(array);
```

Se por acaso mudar, você pode acrescentar `if` *statements* para adequar à sua necessidade.